# Generating pages that require complex calculations and data manipulation

Tags: web, architecture

What's the best approach for generating a page that is the results of complex calculation/data manipulation/api calls (e.g. 5 mins per page)? Obviously I can't do the calculation within my rails web request.

A scheduled task can produce some data, but where should I store it? Should I store it in a postgres table? Should I store it in a document oriented database? Should I store it in memory? Should I generate an html?

I have the feeling of being second-level ignorant about the subject. Is there a well known set of tools to deal with this kind of architectural problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's a pretty broad question to fit SO format. That said...IMO  you're still too vague. I would try an approach (for example a simple AJAX call) to see if it fits your requirements or not. In case it doesn't you can come back with a more specific question. This IMO will attract 10.000 answers (and 80% of them will be equally valid in a specific scenario).

Comment: I guess OP is asking for a "responsive architecture" (and don't exists such thing). All we can do is give some output based on OP input. Performance mean to wisely use resources, sometimes you ill need to trade off. You can spent more CPU and RAM to get less time response, in that case maybe you can store that calculations result to build up a page. Depends on how much can you calculate before user ask for the page for example. How much data storage it ill require etc. A good approach for a responsive web app is to open a ajax call and let the user know the page is loading something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest following approach:

**1. Once you receive initial request:**

You can start processing in a separate thread when you receive the first request with input for calculation and send some token/unique identifier for the request.

**2. Store the result:**

Then start the calculation and store the result in memory using some tool like memcached.

**3. Poll for the result:**

Then the request for fetching the result should keep polling for the result with generated token/unique request identifier. As Adriano said you can use AJAX for that (I am assuming you are getting the requests from Web Browser).